# .htaccess file not working in docker container

Tags: php, docker, .htaccess

I have a PHP project running on Docker. Whenever I include the htaccess file in the project, I get the error "500 Internal Server Error".

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.31
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: demo
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - "./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    networks:
      - lamp-docker
  www:
    depends_on:
      - db
    #image: php:7.4.30-apache
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    build: .
    networks:
      - lamp-docker
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.9.7
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
    networks:
      - lamp-docker
networks:
  lamp-docker:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.30-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)--([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ title.php?title=$1&title_id=$2

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

None of the solutions I found from google worked. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `mod_rewrite` Apache module using `a2enmod rewrite` command in your docker configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding this command in Dockerfile:

```
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

**Note:** after doing this I deleted all images and rebuilt the container.